# jQuery scrollTop and focus on element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, accessibility

I have the following scrollTop function:

```
<a onclick="jQuery('html,body').animate({scrollTop:0},'slow');return false;" class="well well-sm" href="#">
                    <i class="uxf-icon uxf-up-open-large"></i><span class="sr-only">${message:backToTop}</span></a>
```

However, when you use your keyboard to navigate the focus does not go to the top. It remains in the footer. Is there a way to bring the focus to the following div:

```
<div id="top" tabindex="-1"></div>
```

Comment: "...keyboard to navigate..." you mean tab + enter on element?

Comment: @Kriggs, yes I mean tab then enter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The visual focus is different from the keyboard focus, you can use the `focus()` function to define the keyboard focus

```
 <a onclick="jQuery("#top").focus();return false;" class="well well-sm" href="#">...</a>
```

This can be used conjointly with your animate function.

Comment: Thanks. That was exactly what I was looking for. In fact I tried this earlier but without the return false :-(

Answer (score 1):

Animated scrolling to the top of the element, then setting a focus:

```
<script>
    function scroll() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('#top').offset().top
        }, 'slow', function() { 
            $('#top').focus(); 
        });
    }
</script>
<a onclick="scroll(); return false;" class="well well-sm" href="#">...</a>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to change the focus. As it is in an onclick do I need a return false ?

Comment: I added the focus at the end of scrolling too. Yes, you should use `return false;` there.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have assignd a click to it, while enter is a keypress, you have to set it both, here's one way to do it with jQuery delegation:

```
function animateToTop() {
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#top').offset().top
    }, 'slow');
}

$('#aSendToTop').on('click keypress',
    function (e) {
        // mouse 1 has keyCode 1, while enter is keycode 13
        if( [1, 13].indexOf(e.which) > -1 ) animateToTop();
    }
);
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uLhsxema/3/)

Comment: wrong, `onclick` works well with `a[href]` when used with keyboard. (that's an exception)

Comment: @Adam What's the solution without keypress?

Comment: See WCAG SCR35: *While "onclick" sounds like it is tied to the mouse, the onclick event is actually mapped to the default action of a link or button.*